# Flutter: How to place a FloatingActionButton behind a persistent bottom sheet?

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button

I am trying to figure out if it is posible to place a `FloatingActionButton` behind a `BottomSheet` or, in other words, how to make a bottom sheet be in front of **everything** when being shown. I do not mean a modal bottom sheet, but a persistent one. So my question is if it's possible to achieve or if there's some workaround someone might want to share.

[image]

[image]

Here you see the example of the actual behavior when having both a persistent bottom sheet and a floating action button.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){},),
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('showBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet<void>(
                (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text('BottomSheet'),
                      ElevatedButton(
                          child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          })
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use a `Stack` on the `body` instead of `floatingActionButton` like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            const MyStatelessWidget(),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 10,
              right: 10,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('showBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet<void>(
            (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text('BottomSheet'),
                      ElevatedButton(
                          child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          })
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This indeed achieves the desired behavior. I wonder though if there is something less manipulated that could make a bottom sheet always cover things. But maybe a bottom sheet is not the best approach for this. I am not sure but I'm thinking about something like setting the properties of the bottom sheet to achieve this without manipulating a lot the classes outside.

Comment: Try use `enableDrag: true,  isDismissible: false,` on `showModalBottomSheet` to be persistent. To remove the background shadow of modal try use `  barrierColor: Colors.transparent,`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Floating Action button inside column and give sizedBox of dessired heightas children like

```
floatingActionButton: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () async {
            },
            child: const Text('Save'),
          ),
      SizedBox(
        height: _bannerAd!.size.height.toDouble(),
      )
    ],
  ),
```